# How do I reattach a screw to my front wheel's V - brakes, if it has come out? [Pictures attached]

Tags: brakes, mechanical

I noticed today that some ruffians had jammed my bike into my bikestand, and pushed it in so hard, that while pulling it out, one of the brake screws of the V - brakes on the front wheel broke off.

I attempted to tighten the screw using a screwdriver, but it simple wouldn't go in, I don't think there were any threads for the screw inside the hole.

This is a picture of the part which came off:
[image]

This is where the screw and it's bolt are supposed to go, on the front wheel:

[image]

This is the other side of the front wheel, which is normal, and what it used to look like before:

[image]

If someone could give some advice to a newbie on how to fix the V - brake screw, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side note: Are you aware that both your brake pads and the inner tube are misalinged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is more than just a screw coming out, a key piece of the lever arm is broken.

The part that broke off is used to tension in, but the fact it got ripped off means the rest of the lever could be next when you hit the brakes ridingm

Brakes are safety critical parts. Your brake is toast, your only option is replacement.

Comment: Without that part, the brakes will always rub, and wear one pad down quickly.  It will also make lining the brakes up effectively quite hard. Definitely new brakes needed

Answer (score 2):

You can’t fix this. The plastic that the nut was embedded in has been torn away.

Luckily your brake is a construction of plastic over sheet metal so it’s not a terminal issue as long as the brake is working more or less as you need it to. The screw is used to adjust side tension/pad offset from the rim.

Go and buy a new set of V brakes when convenient. They don’t cost too much and most all metal ones will be better brakes than the one you have now.